# When should I use 'view' instead of 'read only' in SharePoint permissions?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm using SharePoint 2007 and I need to know when/where I should use the 'view' instead of 'read-only' for user permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a default [permission matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/markarend/sharepoint-2007-permissions-matrix).

**Read** level has only one more permission than **View Only**

So the users with read level can view the source of the aspx pages, but the users with view only permission can only view the result.