# Difference between "read" "restricted read" and "view only" permissions in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wss

What is the difference between `read`, `restricted read` and `view only` permissions in SharePoint 2007?

***Read*** - Read-only access to the Web site.

***Restricted Read*** - Can view pages and documents, but cannot view historical versions or review user rights information.

***View Only*** - Members of this group can view pages, list items, and documents. If the document has a server-side file handler available, they can only view the document using the server-side file handler.

I can view the above help message beside each and every permission. I can't really understand the `view only` permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These links may also be of some use.

[When should I use 'view' instead of 'read only' in SharePoint permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071942/when-should-i-use-view-instead-of-read-only-in-sharepoint-permissions/4085430#4085430)

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/markarend/sharepoint-2007-permissions-matrix)

The View Only gives you a few extra abilities like:

- View items in lists, documents in document libraries, and view Web discussion comments.
- View past versions of a list item or document.
- View forms, views, and application pages. Enumerate lists.